# Adding a UIImage from the UIImagePickerController to a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a `UIButton` which the user clicks on to bring up a `UIImagePickerController`. Once this has processed, it returns an edited `UIImage` to a delegate handler, which then is supposed to populate the `UIButton` with the new image.

In practise, however, what happens is if the user selects an image from their library, it works fine. But if they take a picture using the camera and edit it, the image doesn't make it to the `UIButton`. However, if I put the same image into a `UIImageView` for test purposes, it shows up.

Moreover, this works fine in the Simulator, but doesn't work on the device. Is it some kind of memory issue? Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)takePictureButtonTapped
{
    UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:nil
                                 delegate:self
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                 destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Take a Photo", @"Upload from Library", nil];

    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [popupQuery showInView:self.view];
    [popupQuery release];

}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:%d", buttonIndex);
    if(buttonIndex == 2)
    {
        // cancel
        [imagePickerController release];
    }
    else
    {
        imagePickerController = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
        imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;

        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            // Take a photo
            // Set up the image picker controller and add it to the view
            imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            // Upload from Library
            imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary] == NO)
                imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        }


        [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo
{
    NSLog(@"imagePickerController::didFinishPickingImage:%@", img);
    itemImage = img;
    [itemImage retain];
    [imageButton setBackgroundImage:itemImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I've tried `setImage`, `setBackgroundImage`, for ALL states, and none of them work. Yet if I put the same image into a `UIImageView`, it's fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey... I earned a "Tumbleweed" badge for this question... Nobody have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that the reason it wasn't working properly was because I was using `didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:` which is DEPRECATED. I should've been using `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` instead. Now it's working perfectly!

For some reason XCode wasn't warning me of the deprecation.